# How to POST to Spotify API token endpoint with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify, node-fetch

I'm running following js-code. But I keep getting an error from Spotify Webpage (saying there was some sort of error).
*credentials* is a base64 encoded string of client_id and secret.

The curl-command works just fine:

```
curl -X "POST" -H "Authorization: Basic *credentials*" -d grant_type=client_credentials https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

The js-code doesn't work properly..

I guess it's pretty easy, but I'm not that good in js (sorry!).

```html
fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic *credentials*'},
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: *"keep getting an error"*... what is the specific error?

Comment: Sorry, the error ist basicly just a blank spotify page saying there was something wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the [Spotify Authorization guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) the body has to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so just add this header:

```
fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic *credentials*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```